# Movement Android Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I m trying to convert the project from Web to Android. Im using the camera with arrow keys, i m trying to touch the screen and go left right up and down.

Here is my code in Web:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Camera.main.transform.position.y < CameraYLimitUp)//Up Camera Mvt
        { transform.Translate(-Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && Camera.main.transform.position.y > CameraYLimitDown)//Down Camera Mvt
        { transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Camera.main.transform.position.x > CameraXLimitLeft)//Left Camera Mvt
        { transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && Camera.main.transform.position.x < CameraXLimitRight)//Right Camera Mvt
        { transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 20); }
```

Thanks for your help

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                 **Update**

```
public float CameraYLimitUp;
public float CameraYLimitDown;
public float CameraXLimitLeft;
public float CameraXLimitRight;
public Vector2 startPos;
public Vector2 endPos;
public bool fingerHold = false;
public bool ButtonPressed = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
CameraYLimitUp = -1f;
CameraYLimitDown = 1f;
CameraXLimitLeft = 1f;
CameraXLimitRight = -1f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y > CameraYLimitUp)
{ transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y < CameraYLimitDown)
{ transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x < CameraXLimitLeft)
{ transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x > CameraXLimitRight)
{ transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

if(!ButtonPressed)
{
if(Input.touchCount > 0){                      
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){       
        startPos = touch.position;             
        fingerHold = true;
    }
    else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved){  
        endPos = touch.position;               
    }
    else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){  
        fingerHold = false;                    
    }
}

if(fingerHold){

    float deltaX = endPos.x - startPos.x;      
    float deltaY = endPos.y - startPos.y;      
    bool horizontal = false;

    if(Mathf.Abs (deltaX) > Mathf.Abs (deltaY)) 
        horizontal = true;                      

    if(horizontal){
        if(deltaX < 0 && transform.position.x < CameraXLimitLeft)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        else if(deltaX > 0 && transform.position.x > CameraXLimitRight)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
    else{ 
        if(deltaY < 0 && transform.position.y < CameraYLimitDown)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        else if(deltaY > 0 && transform.position.y > CameraYLimitUp)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
}
}
}
void OnGUI()
{
 if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 158, 54), "Click Button"))
    {
       ButtonPressed = true; 
       Print("Button Clicked");
    }
 }
```

Comment: So? is anything wrong?

Comment: When i export the project in android i can't goes around using the arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

You can't use arrow keys in Android, you will have to instead simulate something like an analog stick. This script simulates a simple analog stick in Android:

```
public Vector2 startPos;
public Vector2 endPos;
public bool fingerHold = false;

void Update () {
    if(Input.touchCount > 0){                      // get total touches on screen
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){       // when finger starts touching
            startPos = touch.position;             // get its position
            fingerHold = true;
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved){  // when finger moves
            endPos = touch.position;               // get its position too
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){  // when finger released
            fingerHold = false;                    
        }
    }
    if(fingerHold){

        float deltaX = endPos.x - startPos.x;      // get the difference of x position
        float deltaY = endPos.y - startPos.y;      // and the y position
        bool horizontal = false;

        if(Mathf.Abs (deltaX) > Mathf.Abs (deltaY)) // if difference of x is bigger than y
            horizontal = true;                      // meaning we want it to move horizontally

        if(horizontal){
            if(deltaX > 0) // if difference of x is bigger than 0, meaning finger is moving right, translate it to right
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
            else if(deltaX < 0) // the reverse, move left
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else{ // and so on
            if(deltaY > 0)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
            else if(deltaY < 0)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

You can just combine this script with yours, since web doesn't have touches, so this script will not clash with the arrow script.

**My Working Code:**

```
public float CameraYLimitUp;
public float CameraYLimitDown;
public float CameraXLimitLeft;
public float CameraXLimitRight;
public Vector2 startPos;
public Vector2 endPos;
public bool fingerHold = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    CameraYLimitUp = -1f;
    CameraYLimitDown = 1f;
    CameraXLimitLeft = 1f;
    CameraXLimitRight = -1f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y > CameraYLimitUp)
    { transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y < CameraYLimitDown)
    { transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x < CameraXLimitLeft)
    { transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x > CameraXLimitRight)
    { transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 20); }

    if(Input.touchCount > 0){                      
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){       
            startPos = touch.position;             
            fingerHold = true;
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved){  
            endPos = touch.position;               
        }
        else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){  
            fingerHold = false;                    
        }
    }

    if(fingerHold){

        float deltaX = endPos.x - startPos.x;      
        float deltaY = endPos.y - startPos.y;      
        bool horizontal = false;

        if(Mathf.Abs (deltaX) > Mathf.Abs (deltaY)) 
            horizontal = true;                      

        if(horizontal){
            if(deltaX < 0 && transform.position.x < CameraXLimitLeft)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 10);
            else if(deltaX > 0 && transform.position.x > CameraXLimitRight)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
        else{ 
            if(deltaY < 0 && transform.position.y < CameraYLimitDown)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);
            else if(deltaY > 0 && transform.position.y > CameraYLimitUp)
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Try comparing it with yours

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working , but my problem now that i can't limit the movement of the camera in the right side , when i add for exemple this condition  if (deltaX > 0  && Camera.main.transform.position.x < CameraXLimitRight)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by this `Camera.main.transform.position.x < CameraXLimitRight`. So are you moving the camera itself?

Comment: I am trying to define limits of camera so that I cannot scroll too far in either the x or y coordinates. I m moving the camera  when the camera reaches a limit in right , left , up and down sides it should stop. for exemple [float CameraXLIMITRight = 15;] is the variable i am using to limit the movement of the camera is the right , when i touch the screen in the right side of the device , the camera should move and when it reaches 15 it should stop and not go too far. it's the same for left , up and down

Comment: Are you sure the conditions you set are correct? I tested your code above and it didn't work. So I made a working code tested both in web and my android device. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hello Jay Kazama , Thanks a lot for your help everything is working very well  ,  i have a big problem that a created a gui button when i export the apk to device and i touch anywhere i can move the camera, when i click on button  i can also touch the camera, i created a bool variable [ButtonPressed]. when i press the gui button this variable is true and when i touch anywhere in screen it is false. but it's not working . Can you please see the Update part of my post above. Thanks a lot again

Comment: Sorry, I seem to unable to help you this time. I have tried EVERYTHING, giving conditions for the inputs to run like your code, separating the scripts (1 script for input key and touches, 1 script for OnGUI) and then disable the input script when OnGUI pressed, I even removed the input script itself on runtime. But nothing worked, the camera still moves on GUI touch. I don't know what this is, a bug or something? It shouldn't be possible for the code to run if the script itself is disabled or removed. Try posting new a question of this, see if the others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check out the mobile controls, just import the Standart Assests (Mobile)* package and take a look at the First and Third Person Controller prefabs and, of course, at the Character Controller scripts from the package. It's all is pretty straightforward from there.

*(Assets -> Import Package -> Standart Assets (Mobile))

[Credit goes here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/406789/modifying-destop-game-into-androidipad-touch-scree.html)